# .net core Dockerfile template duplicate WORKDIR

Tags: docker, .net-core

New project template for .net core with docker support contains this default Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj", "WebApplication/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

Can someone explain to me why `WORKDIR /app` is specified 2 times - for base and for final?
When I try to comment out any of it - it still works in exactly same way.

Comment: it is not specified in the same image build but one in base and one in final

Comment: but what's the purpose to specify it in base? there are no COPY or CMD command to be affected by WORKDIR.. And since we are discussing `base` - why ports are exposed in `base`, instead of `final`?